# Convert eregi function to php 5.3

Tags: php, regex, eregi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

How do i convert this code to php 5.3:

```
if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) { }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/VERIFIED/i",$this->ipn_response)) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a fixed text like `VERIFIED` you shouldn't use regular expressions because they use unnecessary overhead.

```
if(stripos('VERIFIED', $this->ipn_response) !== false) { }
```

That should also do the job. Note that `stripos()` returns the position of the string you are looking for, so it could return zero to indicate a match. It returns boolean false if the string you are looking for is not present.